# Angular 8 - not assignable to AsyncValidatorFn

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create custom validator function in reactive form. Code:

form.component.ts

```
...
    form = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(3)
        ],
            UsernameService.isUnique
        )
    });
...
```

username.service.ts

```
...
    static isUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({ notUnique: true });
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
...
```

There is an error shown while hovering on `UsernameService.isUnique` -

> "Argument type (control: AbstractControl) => Promise< ValidationErrors
>   | null > is not assignable to parameter type AsyncValidatorFn |
>   AsyncValidatorFn[] | null"

Why this error exists? According to documentation (https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn) I used proper call signature of AsyncValidatorFn.

Comment: Did you try to use the `isUnique`-method without `static` modifyer? Use `public` instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There was a typescript problem - importing bad type(?) of `Promise`, I had to add install this module

`npm i --save bluebird`

and use this as Promise import in component:

`import * as Promise from 'bluebird';`

Answer (score 9):

**The solution is actually very simple --**

add **"as AsyncValidatorFn"** behind **"UsernameService.isUnique":**

```
      UsernameService.isUnique as AsyncValidatorFn
```

or add **AsyncValidatorFn** before it within "<>":

```
      <AsyncValidatorFn>UsernameService.isUnique
```

Of course, **AsyncValidatorFn** needs to be imported:

```
      import { AsyncValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
```

**Example in practice:**

The following picture shows that there is an error **WITHOUT "as AsyncValidatorFn":**

[image]

The error message is about the same:

```
      Argument of type '(control: FormControl) => 
      Promise<any> | Observable<any>' is not assignable to
      parameter of type 'AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[]'
```

The following shows that the error **DISAPPEARED** after **"as AsyncValidatorFn"** is added (behind):

[image]

or (before):

[image]

The following is the **"forbiddenEmails"** function:

[image]

**Actually, you can solve many similar problems in the same way.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial you can try https://www.netjstech.com/2020/11/custom-async-validator-angular-reactive-form.html